# Make apk file with ant

Tags: android, ant, apk

I want to export signed apk file from my Android Project with a terminal command line in my mac.

first of all i understand i need to make a build.xml file and i do it with :

```
./android update project -p MY_PROJECT_FOLDER
```

then the build.xml file was create and i this command:

```
ant release
```

then there was 3 apk files in the bin directory, i moved the file : `MyProject-release.apk`
to my android device, and when i try to run it it give me an error.

some stuff i found :

1. if i run the project from eclipse it run on the device with out any problem.
2. if i use android tools in eclipse to make signed apk file, it run without problem.
3. if i run it from eclipse the apk in the device is bigger than the apk i make from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is that ant release builds an UNSIGNED apk file. You need to sign it before you can install it on your device. You can find an example [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/).

If that does not solve the problem. Please provide additional information about the error.